# Как правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Школьница рассказывает, что учитель поправил ее, когда она написала "миллионы людей отдали свои жизни...". Мол, надо "свою жизнь". Но разве эти два варианта не равнозначны?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант школьницы не кажется мне ошибочным. Я бы не поправляла. Второй вариант тоже верный. Возможно, помимо основного значения отдали жизнь(и)-перестали существовать, во втором случае присутствует значение того, чем наполнена жизнь (любовь, дети, счастье и т.д.), т.е. второе употребление более образное. ИМХО.

Answer (score 0):

У Розенталя есть на эту тему информация (см. в книге «Говорите и пишите по-русски правильно»). Там говорится, что если дополнение относится к нескольким предметам (лицам), то необходимо использовать форму единственного числа.

Например: *Солдаты были вознаграждены орденом*. Здесь подразумевается, что орден получил каждый солдат.

Я всё-таки остаюсь при мнении, что это не совсем грубая ошибка.